# How to collapse only selected row ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to toggle only the selected row, but I can't do that?

Check my code all and demonstration is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-trainin-2-gv9glh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

I'm currently toggle all the row and I only want the row where it was clicked.

Here 90 line of code. Here is start:

```
  <div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of trainingExercises; let i = index;">
   
    <div class="single-exe" [class]="{ 'collapse-row' : collapse}">
      <h1 class="exerciseNameAbsolute"> {{ training.exerciseName }}</h1>
      <i (click)="collapse = !collapse" class="dx-icon-collapse dx-icon-custom-style"></i>
```

Comment: If you want to toggle only one row, then each row needs its own variable to control if it is toggled or not.

Comment: You already have an associated `training` variable that you are using to generate the markup that can be collapsed.  Perhaps you could put an extra `collapse` variable on that contextual variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of trainingExercises; let i = index;">
   
    <div class="single-exe" [class]="{ 'collapse-row' : training.collapse}">
      <h1 class="exerciseNameAbsolute"> {{ training.exerciseName }}</h1>
      <i (click)="training.collapse = !training.collapse" class="dx-icon-collapse dx-icon-custom-style"></i>
```

This is the suggestion I made from the comment.  Add a `collapse` property to each of your `training` variables and default it to true/false depending upon what state you want them to start out in.  Change your `[class]` to look at that scoped variable, and when you click the element that toggles the collapse, toggle that variable on the training variable.